android adb how to send input tap continuous with delay 0s
I want to create a program to auto tap continuous to screen android phone.
I tried "adb shell input tap x y" in LOOP but so slow (about 1s).
I tried multiple command like: "adb shell input tap x1 y1 && adb shell input tap x2 y2" but can not resolve my problem.
How to do this action? I send an gift image for detail.


The command is slow because every time you have to establish adb communication, create a new shell and then execute the command. Instead open adb shell and then write and execute a sh shell script on Android side that executes input tap x y  in a loop.

oh I can understand your solution. Can you tell me how to execute a command inside phone?

juts execute adb shell and you are getting a shell on the device.

@Robert I don't know your suggestion :v can you give a topic on Stackoverflow, I tried search but not found any solution. Many thanks!

As @Robert mentioned, running only 1 adb shell and then executing input tap in a loop will increase the rate.
However you can achieve better rates avoiding executing a new input every time.
Using AndroidViewClient/culebra with CulebraTester2-public backend you will be able to obtain values like this.
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import timeit
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

helper = ViewClient.view_client_helper()
print(f"{timeit.timeit('helper.ui_device.click(500, 500)', number=1, globals=globals()):.4f}s")

giving (on a emulator):
⚠️  CulebraTester2 server should have been started and localport 9987 redirected to remote port 9987.
0.1796s

So you can run
helper.ui_device.click(x, y)

in a loop to tap very fast.
